# Spring: Persisting a list of attributes which has list of other attributes in itself

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to make webservice for food order management . I have a Entities Product and Restaurant and I am struggling to make Order Entity .

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", referencedColumnName = "id",  insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Restaurant restaurant;
    private int restaurant_id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
}

@Entity
public class Restaurant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String phone;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Product> menu;
}
```

I want the Order entity to have a List. If i keep an attribute OrderId in Product , to Join tables Product and Order, will that be a good idea? Is there any better way to do it?

PS: I don't want to keep order Id with Product because i think Product should not be aware of it

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you want ? You want an Order entity with a List of Product, that's right ? What is the relation with Restaurant ? Can you describe the cardinality between entities you want to have ?

Comment: @cactuschibre Yes, I want Order entity to have a list of products. An Order will have a restaurant_id which will be the column to Join Restaurant and Order.So Order and Restaurant will have one-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a fine idea.

You can use List in Order entity and join them by having id of order in product.

it's kinda hard to tell what you really want, but this site (under headline relationships) has description of best practices for likely to all of your use cases!

https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/

Cheers!